# How to write a file into preference store in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to write a CSS file into the preference store instead of into a local file path and read back whenever it requires.

I am new to Eclipse, an example would be helpful for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preference store is for **key-value-pairs**, not for files.

See ***[Eclipse Preferences - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html)***

Answer (score 1):

The preference store is for fairly small values stored using a 'key' and a 'value'. You could put the contents of the file as a 'value' but this is probably not a good use of the store.

Eclipse plugins can use the 'state location' to save files. Use something like:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);

File dir = path.toFile();
```

to get the path to the state location directory. Your plugin can store anything it likes in this directory,

`Platform` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform`